# PHP - Parse SDK query on ParseGeoPoint doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform

I've got an issue that I can't fix, it's been weeks I'm trying to do so but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or if there's something wrong in the Parse PHP SDK.

I have built a website with **Parse Server** as the backend, it's a listing website with location detection, and I'm working on Chrome (I've tried Firefox and Safari as well, I get the same issue).

My steps:

1. When you got to the home page, the browser asks you to allow location detection, I allow it.
2. If you click on the location button, you can open a Google map into a modal and place the pin on click to the desired location, you can also set the distance range by moving a slider. I select London, UK
3. I get the right console messages in Chrome:

   DISTANCE: 87 Km 

   MARKER LAT: 51.522497992110246 - MARKER LNG: -0.12863733794108612

The issue comes here, the website shows only some of the posted Ads,  those ones that I have posted through a mobile app (my own source code too, with Parse iOS and Android SDKs), **it doesn't display those ads I've submitted through the website**. Weird thing, if I post ads from the website and I open my mobile app, I can see them!

And if I check my database, the GeoPoint coordinates of my ads are correctly stored, whether I submitted ads through the website or the mobile apps.

Lastly, If I perform a search by keywords with the search bar on the top of the page, I can find those ads I've posted through the website. So, basically, no keywords, no ads posted through the website...

Here's my PHP code to query ads (NOTE; the variables that start with `$ADS_` are simple strings declared in another file, ex. `$ADS_LOCATION` = `"ads_location"`, etc):

```
/*--- variables ---*/
$isFollowing = $_GET['isFollowing'];
$option = $_GET['option'];
$upObjID = $_GET['upObjID'];
$latitude = $_GET['lat'];   // 51.522497992110246
$longitude = $_GET['lng'];  // -0.12863733794108612
$dist = $_GET['distance'];
$distance = (int)$dist;     // 50
$category = $_GET['category'];
$sortBy = str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['sortBy']);
$keywords = preg_split('/\s+/', $_GET['keywords']);

// query Ads
try {
   $query = new ParseQuery($ADS_CLASS_NAME);
   $query->equalTo($ADS_IS_REPORTED, false);

   // it's following.php
   if ($isFollowing == true) {
      $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
      $cuObjIdArr = array(); 
      array_push($cuObjIdArr, $currentUser->getObjectId());
      $query->containedIn($ADS_FOLLOWED_BY, $cuObjIdArr);

   // it's User profile page
   } else if ($upObjID != null) {
      $userPointer = new ParseUser($USER_CLASS_NAME, $upObjID);
      $userPointer->fetch();
      $query->equalTo($ADS_SELLER_POINTER, $userPointer);

      if ($option == 'selling'){ $query->equalTo($ADS_IS_SOLD, false);
      } else if ($option == 'sold'){ $query->equalTo($ADS_IS_SOLD, true); 
      } else if ($option == 'liked'){ $query->containedIn($ADS_LIKED_BY, array($userPointer->getObjectId())); }

   // it's index.php
   } else {

      // nearby Ads
      if ($latitude != null  &&  $longitude != null) {
         $currentLocation = new ParseGeoPoint($latitude, $longitude);

         $query->withinKilometers("location", $currentLocation, $distance);


      // nearby DEFAULT LOCATION COORDINATES
      } else { 
         $defaultLocation = new ParseGeoPoint($DEFAULT_LOCATION_LATITUDE, $DEFAULT_LOCATION_LONGITUDE);

         $query->withinKilometers($ADS_LOCATION, $defaultLocation, $DISTANCE_IN_KM); 

      }

      // keywords
      if (count($keywords) != 0) { $query->containedIn($ADS_KEYWORDS, $keywords); }

      // category
      if ($category != "All") { $query->equalTo($ADS_CATEGORY, $category); }

      // sort by
      switch ($sortBy) {
         case 'Newest': $query->descending("createdAt");
            break;
         case 'Price:lowtohigh': $query->ascending($ADS_PRICE);
            break;
         case 'Price:hightolow': $query->descending($ADS_PRICE);
            break;
         case 'MostLiked': $query->descending($ADS_LIKES);
            break;

         default: break;
      }// ./ sort by

   }// ./ If


   // perform query
   $adsArray = $query->find(); 
   if (count($adsArray) != 0) {
      for ($i = 0;  $i < count($adsArray); $i++) {
         // Parse Obj
         $adObj = $adsArray[$i];

         // image 1
         $adImg = $adObj->get($ADS_IMAGE1);
         // title
         $adTitle = substr ($adObj->get($ADS_TITLE), 0, 24).'...';
         // currency
         $adCurrency = $adObj->get($ADS_CURRENCY);
         // price
         $adPrice = $adObj->get($ADS_PRICE);

         echo '
            <!-- Ad card -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 portfolio-item">
               <div class="card">
         ';

         // Sold badge
         $isSold = $adObj->get($ADS_IS_SOLD);
         if ($isSold) { echo '<div class="card-sold-badge"><img src="assets/images/sold-badge.png"></div>'; }
         echo '
            <a href="ad-info.php?adObjID='.$adObj->getObjectId().'"><img src="'.$adImg->getURL().'"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
               <p class="card-title"><a href="ad-info.php?adObjID='.$adObj->getObjectId().'">'.$adTitle.'</a></p>
               <p class="card-price">'.$adCurrency.' '.$adPrice.'</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         ';
      }// ./ For

   // no ads
   } else {
      echo '
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 40px; font-weight: 600">No Ads found.</div>
         </div>
      ';
   }

// error
} catch (ParseException $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }
```

The above code comes from a separate file called `query-ads.php` and it gets displayed in a div:

```
<div class="row" id="adsGrid"></div>
```

I perform an AJAX function to call `query-ads.php`:

```
function queryAds(catName, keywords) {
        // category
        if (catName == null) { catName = "All"; }
        document.getElementById("categoryName").innerHTML = '<h5 id="categoryName"><strong>' + catName + '</strong></h5>';
        // keywords
        if (keywords == null) { keywords = ''; }

        // console.log('KEYWORDS: ' + keywords);
        // console.log('LAT: ' + latitude + ' -- LNG: ' + longitude);
        console.log('DISTANCE: ' + distance + ' Km');
        // console.log('SORT BY: ' + sortBy);

        $.ajax({
            url:'query-ads.php',
            data: 'lat=' + latitude + '&lng=' + longitude + '&distance=' + distance + '&category=' + catName + '&keywords=' + keywords + '&sortBy=' + sortBy,
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(data) {
                document.getElementById("adsGrid").innerHTML = data;
            }, 
            // error
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                swal(err.Message);
        }});
    }
```

And here's my JavaScript code as well:

var cityStateButton = document.getElementById("cityState");

```
/*--- variables --*/
// localStorage.clear();

var latitude = localStorage.getItem('latitude');
var longitude = localStorage.getItem('longitude');
var distance = localStorage.getItem('distance');
if (distance == null) { distance = 50; }
var map;
var markers = [];
var geocoder;
var sortBy = document.getElementById('sortByBtn').innerHTML;
console.log("1st LATITUDE: " + latitude + " -- 1st LONGITUDE: " + longitude + ' -- 1st DISTANCE: ' + distance + ' -- 1st SORT BY: ' + sortBy);


// Call functions
if (latitude == null) { getCurrentLocation();
} else { getAddress(); }



// ------------------------------------------------
// MARK: - GET CURRENT LOCATION
// ------------------------------------------------
function getCurrentLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, showError);

    } else { 
        swal("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");

        // set default location coordinates
        latitude =  <?php echo $DEFAULT_LOCATION_LATITUDE ?>;
        longitude = <?php echo $DEFAULT_LOCATION_LONGITUDE ?>;
        getAddress();
    }
}

function getPosition(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    getAddress();
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            swal("You have denied your current Location detection.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            swal("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;            
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            swal("The request to get your current location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            swal("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }

    // set default location
    latitude = <?php echo $DEFAULT_LOCATION_LATITUDE ?>;
    longitude = <?php echo $DEFAULT_LOCATION_LONGITUDE ?>;
    getAddress();
}

function getAddress () {   
    // geocoding API
    var geocodingAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&key=<?php echo $GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY ?>";
    $.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {
        if (json.status == "OK") {
            var result = json.results[0];
            var city = "";
            var state = "";
            for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                var ac = result.address_components[i];
                if (ac.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) { city = ac.short_name; }
                if (ac.types.indexOf("country") >= 0) { state = ac.short_name; }
            }// ./ For

            // show city, state
            cityStateButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i> &nbsp;' + city + ', ' + state;

            // call query
            queryAds();

            // save gps coordinates
            localStorage.setItem('latitude', latitude);
            localStorage.setItem('longitude', longitude);
            // console.log("LAT (getAddress): " + latitude + " -- LNG (getAddress): " + longitude);

            // call function
            initMap();

        }// ./ If
    });
}



//---------------------------------
// MARK - INIT GOOGLE MAP
//---------------------------------
var mapZoom = 12;
function initMap() {  
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: mapZoom,
        center: location,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControl: false
    });

    // call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
    map.addListener('click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });

    // Add a marker in the center of the map.
    addMarker(location);
}


function addMarker(location) {
    clearMarkers();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    // set lat & lng based on marker's coordinates
    latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
    longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
    console.log("MARKER LAT: " + latitude + " - MARKER LNG: " + longitude);

    // zoom & center map based on pin
    metersPerPx = 156543.03392 * Math.cos(latitude * Math.PI / 180) / Math.pow(2, mapZoom)
    map.setZoom(metersPerPx/2.6);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());        
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }// ./ For
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() { 
    setMapOnAll(null);
    markers = [];
}



//---------------------------------
// MARK - GET GPS COORDS FROM ADDRESS
//---------------------------------
function getCoordsFromAddress(address) {   
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            markers.push(marker);

            // set coordinates
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            // save gps coordinates
            localStorage.setItem('latitude', latitude);
            localStorage.setItem('longitude', longitude);

            // console.log("SEARCH LOCATION LAT: " + latitude + " - SEARCH LOCATION LNG: " + longitude);

            initMap();

        // error
        } else { swal('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status); 
    }});
}
```

I thought it was an issue with `ParseGeoPoint`, but it's not, because if I make a text search for keywords, I can find Ads.

Comment: Your code is not minimal and can't be used as it is to reproduce the issue. We don't have any of your data, we don't know what you have tried to debug. What is `$ADS_LOCATION`? Where is it defined? Website *shows only some of the posted Ads* ... Why? Which are returned? Which are not? As it is, this question should be closed.

Comment: well, maybe closing this question is too much, it would have been nicer to just stop after giving suggestions about to improve this question :) This is what make the world a better place

Comment: $ADS_LOCATION is just a string declared in another php file, it’s “location”, when you build Parse Server queries, you need to set the column name of your database as the first parameter

Comment: I know what it's supposed to be. That's why I am asking what's in there. Still, we don't have your data so I can't think of how anyone could help but I might be wrong... I meant it should be closed as I would vote to close it but bounty questions can't be closed. Questions should contain a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this one doesn't.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I understand your point, maybe the question should simply be: "Does the ParseGeoPoint query work fine on the Parse Server's PHP SDK?". Because, as explained in my question, the database shows all correct data, so if I post an Ad via the website, it gets displayed in the mobile app but NOT the wesbite. Viceversa, If i post an Ad from the mobile app, it gets displayed in the website (and of course the app too) :(

Comment: @MrUpsidown nevermind, I've found a solution, it was a small bug in the Parse Server PHP SDK which doesn't filter items properly if the keywords Array doesn't have at least a blank item: ""

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I'm posting it just in case someone else will encounter such issue on the Parse PHP SDK, because it's there since early 2018.

In my script that saves Ads in my database, I was storing lowercase keywords based on the description  and title of submitted items:

```
$kStr = $description. " " .$title. " " .$currentUser->getUsername();
$keywords = explode( " ", strtolower($kStr) );
```

Which was working fine, but since the PHP `ParseQuery` with a keywords filter needs at least an empty item in the array of keywords, I had to add this simple line below the above code:

```
array_push($keywords, "");
```

In this way, the database stores all proper keywords + an empty one: **""**, here's an example of how the keywords Arrat-type field looks like in the database:

```
[
  "lorem",
  "ad",
  "ipsum",
  "johndoe",
  "" <-- this is the empty item that the SDK needs to properly perform a query in case of additional filters (in my case, a ParseGeopoint one)
]
```

This may be just a temporary trick until Parse Server's developers will fix this issue. It works, so why not ;)